# How to use the PhoneGap Barcode Scanner plugin without Eclipse?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, zxing

The official readme of the plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner#readme

explains how to use the BarcodeScanner plugin using eclipse.

I currently develop without using Eclipse, how can I integrate the library to my project?

Without replicating the Eclipse library integration step my project does not build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin too and see if it works: http://www.scandit.com/support/getting-started-with-the-scandit-phonegap-plugin-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line in the android tools:

```
android update project --target <target_ID> --path path/to/your/project --library path/to/library_project
```

You have to set the library path relative to your project. I only did it putting the library in the same workspace as my project.

More informations:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/pull/893

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

if you have subprojects in your project you can use the -s parameter in the end of the command line

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone:
https://github.com/zeroasterisk/PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Example-iOS

Specifically:

Installed the plugin (in a handful of paths) but kept the one which worked. Implemented a basic JS scanner code to demonstrate functionality: auto-runs on load, auto-reloads on error, alerts on success/failure/cancel.

NOTE: the comments on the barcodescanner.js and index.js, both mention my customization of the define/require object paths. I could not get the demo/example paths to work, after several permutations.

(this is iOS only atm, but I plan on making an Android example too)